# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have created a jersey web service and deployed it in tomcat 8. When I run it in local machine I am not facing any issue. But when I deploy it in aws I am getting the below exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:739)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$26.run(WebApplicationImpl.java:1626)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createProxy(WebApplicationImpl.java:1623)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.&lt;init&gt;(WebApplicationImpl.java:335)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl.createWebApplication(WebApplicationProviderImpl.java:55)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:66)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.create(ServletContainer.java:412)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.create(ServletContainer.java:327)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:603)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't find any related link. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Cross check your jars.classnotfound are 99% due to jars/dependencies not properlt defined

Comment: @Akshay Thanks for the prompt reply. I find that most of the jar ar available in the war file. I added jar-with-dependencies plugin to include the jar inside the war file. However I ll check once again

Comment: @Akshay I don't know which jar file the class $Proxy8 correponds to. I don't find any mismmatches in other jar files

Comment: Not really,ClassNotFountException is different from NoClassDefFoundError. ClassNotFountException mostly happend when jvm failed to 'load' class file.And NoClassDefFoundError mostly happend when jvm try to create a instance with out instance Class has been initialize successfully,